# What changes are needed to prevent Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on the following query

```
UPDATE contacts 
SET count = count + 1, 
contact_id = (@contact_id := contact_id) 
WHERE count = 0
ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC 
LIMIT 1;
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE contact_id = @contact_id;
```

It through following warning,

```
Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
```

Please tell me what changes are needed to prevent this warning?

Comment: If so use `SELECT .. INTO @contact_id .. FOR UPDATE` then `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Akina I need to UPDATE first to prevent the selection of this row again.

Comment: FOR UPDATE locks selected row and prevents this row selection by concurrent thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
-- select one row for update and lock it
SELECT contact_id, ts_contact_scraped
INTO @contact_id, @ts_contact_scraped
FROM contacts 
WHERE count = 0
ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC 
FOR UPDATE;
-- update locked row
UPDATE contacts
SET count = count + 1
WHERE contact_id = @contact_id
  AND ts_contact_scraped = @ts_contact_scraped;
-- get new state of updated row
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE contact_id = @contact_id
  AND ts_contact_scraped = @ts_contact_scraped;
```

`contacts (contact_id, ts_contact_scraped)` must be defined as unique.